# Run installing suggestions of the Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

Sometimes you try to run a command and the terminal says :

command not found but can be installed with :

sudo apt-get install xxxx

Is there a way to just run this installation instead of retyping the whole thing ?

Comment: Why not copy that command?

Comment: xy problem, which if you add that then any typo would start installing something

Comment: I mean like something with the keyboard, like i just press up then enter to run again the previous command.

Comment: I dont get what is unclear about my question. It would like many other events in the terminal. For example, lets figure :

command not found but can be installed with :

sudo apt-get install xxxx

do you want to install it (y or n) ?

y

xxx has been installed

Comment: all the source code is available.  Please show your attempt and where you have a problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think if you say is there a way not to copy the `sudo xxx` and paste it back probably it is a clearer question, and add "open for other methods"

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if any thing that exists for ubuntu and apt, thou you may ry [thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck) it corrects errors in previous console commands. Btw the exists for pacman based systems.